# How to stress test my udp server with a certain packet size and speed

Tags: c#, udp, stress-testing, udpclient

I have a udp server on a different network that listens for packets coming in.

I have a client (written in c#) that attempts to send 10 packets of 4000 bytes every second.

I am testing many clients from the same machine/network.

At the moment I am testing 10 clients.

This is my c# client:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (var index = 0; index < 10; index++)
        {
            var test = new UdpLocalServerUploaderService();
            var th = new Thread(test.Start);
            var intBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(index);
            th.Start(intBytes);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    internal  class UdpLocalServerUploaderService
    {
        private static UdpClient _udpClient;
        private static string Uri = "my server";
        private const int Port = 8200;

        public  void Start(object token)
        {
            var data = new byte[4000];
            data[0] =( (byte[]) token)[0];
            data[1] = ((byte[])token)[1];
            data[2] = ((byte[])token)[2];
            data[3] = ((byte[])token)[3];

            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            _udpClient = new UdpClient(Uri, Port);
            while (true)
            {
                _udpClient.Send(data, data.Length);
                Thread.Sleep((100));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my server c#

```
    public void StartListening(object port)
    {
        try
        {
            var ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, (int)port);
            var newsock = new UdpClient(ipep);
            var sender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

            EvLogger?.Invoke(LoggerName.Info, "Listening");
            // EvUdpStatus?.Invoke(true);
            var data = newsock.Receive(ref sender);

            while (true)
            {
                data = newsock.Receive(ref sender);
                EvLogger?.Invoke(LoggerName.Debug, DateTime.Now + "\t" +  BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 0));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            EvLogger?.Invoke(LoggerName.Error, ex);

        }
    }
```

I can look at the logs created and I can see 10 packets are received for 10 clients every second.

Now, If I 'max' this out to 100 clients there are a lot of missing packets and I struggle to even ftp into my server.

Now may I assume that the maximum number of bytes (per second) I can upload from my client is a set figure and the receiving amount I can receive into my server is also a maximum number of bytes per second?

Is if fair to say I would need clients on different networks to properly test the maximum number of bytes that can be received into my server?

Sorry if this is all obvious but just wanted peoples viewpoints.

Thanks

Comment: Usual internet MTU is 1500 bytes. You are sending 4000 bytes. UDP doesn't support packet fragmentation and also is not reliable. Maybe that's why you are missing many pakcets.

Comment: Thanks I switched host provider and I can now send 4K packets. Udp does support fragmentation it just does not guarantee it.